# Combinations of 5 Member Commitees Selected From 8 people

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> 2.1 Eight people, including Mary and Peter, are candidates to serve on a committee of ﬁve.
>
> (a) How many diﬀerent committees are possible?
>
> (b) How many diﬀerent committees are there that contain both Mary and Peter?
>
> (c) How many diﬀerent committees are there that contain neither Mary nor Peter?
>
> (d) How many diﬀerent committees are there that contain either Mary or Peter or possibly both of them?
>
> (e) How many diﬀerent committees are there that contain just one of Mary or Peter?

I am struggling to think of methods for questions of this type, is there a way to know how to answer questions like this?

my answer for (a) was 8x5 is that correct?

Comment: Not even close.

Comment: then what is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) you have 8 people and must select 5.  Count the ways.

There's a choice of 8 people for the 'first' person, then 7 people for the 'second' and so on.  However the order of selection does not matter here, and there are $5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ ways to arrange those people, so we have $\frac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$ ways to select 5 people from 8 in any order.

This is $\dfrac {8!}{5!\;3!}$, also expressed as $\dbinom{8}{5}$ or ${^8{\rm C}_5}$.

This should be familiar; revise "Combinations and Permutations".